# cant get the content of the jsonresult data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

client make get request to web api then get response as json data here is tho request and the web api that post response to client data..

This is web api method, after some process post response to client;

```cs
public ActionResult GetBooks(){
    ...
    return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = totalRecords, data = booklist },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
}
```

and here is the client getting response from web api and post it to view:

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks/").Result;
JsonResult result = null;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonResult>().Result;
}
List<Book> booklist = null;

return Json(new { draw = result.Data.draw, recordsFiltered = result.Data.totalRecords, recordsTotal = result.Data.totalRecords, data = result.Data.booklist }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

as you see same properties I try to get them with `result.Data.propertyName`
but couldn't.

I don't want to change return property names in client method.

What shall I do?

here is response(result.) data look like:

```
{{
  "draw": "1",
  "recordsFiltered": 670,
  "recordsTotal": 670,
  "data": [ 
    {
      "Title": "A Popular Survey of the Old Testament",
      "Publisher": "Baker Academic",
      "Description": "Illustrated with photos, charts, and maps, and written in their understanding of Old Testament people and events.",
      "Authors": [
        "Norman L. Geisler"
      ],
      "Id": "579273aa2711d31de88933bd"
    },

    {
      "Title": "A Village on the Moon / Um Povoado Na Lua",
      "Publisher": "Trafford Publishing",
      "Description": "Since the beginning of time, mankind has looked up at the Moon and wondered. Many have seen figures on that light in the sky and universo. Um grupo de aventureiros se propôs a colonizar esse planeta e aqui está a sua história.",
      "Authors": [
        "Charles A. Hindley"
      ],
      "Id": "579273aa2711d31de8893438"
    }
  ]
}}
```

in proper json format we are able to get data with `result.Data.draw` and `result.Data.data[0]` but in this case I am in trouble..

how can I remove excess scopes ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. uncertain about what you are asking. what is the extra scope you want removed

Comment: Hello, check the daha it begins with "{{" double scopes.. its not correct right.. I dont understand why its happen and how can I fix it

Comment: Ok now I understand what you are asking.

Comment: re-reading and formulating an idea. So far my focus is on `result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonResult>().Result`. something about readingthe response like that doesn't seem right to me

Comment: The Raw Json in your example. is that from the first snippet or the second

Comment: its second(result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<JsonResult>().Result)
I check the content of result here... and see the incorrect json format data as you see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inner scope the following models can be derived for the client.

```cs
public class BookData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string[] Authors { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class GetBooksResult
{
    public string draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public BookData[] data { get; set; }
}
```

With that

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Book/GetBooks/");
GetBooksResult result = null;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<GetBooksResult>();
}
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

On the client the response is raw json string being returned form the web api. No need for `JsonResult`. You parse the data returned into the models on the client side and pass that on.